# How do I detach the connector from this headlight assembly to replace the bulb?

Tags: mazda, lights, miata

I want to replace a broken headlight bulb in a European 1999 Mazda MX-5 NB 1.6L (also known as a Miata mark II). How do I detach the power connector so that I can get to the light fixture?

The connector looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Both pictures show the same connector, just from a different position and angle.

There's a rubber ring with the number `99223-80008` on it, visible in the photos. It seems to be a dust cover produced by Koito. I *think* it can only be removed after removing the power connector, but I'm not sure.

I've searched for tutorials, but none that I could find had a connector like this.

Answer (score 2):

The connector can simply be pulled out. There are no screws nor latches or anything. It's held in place by the three electrical contact pins (H4) of the bulb, so purely by fiction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have something very similar on a motorcycle.

You peel back the rubber cover and then you can access the connector.

Comment: In the mean time, I found a picture of the rubber cover here: https://www.newmiltonautoparts.com/koito-99226-80008--vauxhall-frontera--nissan-navara-headlight-headlamp-rear-bulb-cover-dust-cap-12133-p.asp. Judging by that picture, the cover has a centre "circle" that sits behind the connector, so the connector would have to be removed first